# Evaluating $\int \sqrt{\frac{5-x}{x-2}}\,dx$ with two different methods and getting two different results

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried Evaluating $\int \sqrt{\dfrac{5-x}{x-2}}dx$ using two different methods and got two different results.

Getting two different answers when tried using two different methods:-

**M-$1$:**

$$\int \dfrac{5-x}{\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}}dx$$
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{-2x+7}{\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}}dx+\dfrac{3}{2}\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}}$$
$$\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}+\dfrac{3}{2}\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{-x^2+7x-10}}$$

$$\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}+\dfrac{3}{2}\int\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\dfrac{7}{2}\right)^2}}$$

$$\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}+\dfrac{3}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{x-\dfrac{7}{2}}{\dfrac{3}{2}}$$

$$\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}+\dfrac{3}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{2x-7}{3}$$

**M-$2$:**

$$x=5\sin^2\theta+2\cos^2\theta$$
$$dx=\left(10\sin\theta\cos\theta-4\cos\theta\sin\theta\right) \, d\theta$$
$$\int \sqrt{\dfrac{5\cos^2\theta-2\cos^2\theta}{5\sin^2\theta-2\sin^2\theta}}\cdot6\sin\theta\cos\theta \,d\theta$$
$$6\int \cos^2\theta \,d\theta$$
$$\int 3\left(1+\cos2\theta\right) \,d\theta$$
$$3\left(\theta+\dfrac{\sin2\theta}{2}\right)$$
$$3\theta+\dfrac{3}{2}\sin2\theta$$

$$x=5\sin^2\theta+2-2\sin^2\theta$$
$$\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{3}}=\theta$$

$$\cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$$
$$\cos2\theta=1-2\cdot\dfrac{x-2}{3}$$
$$\cos2\theta=\dfrac{7-2x}{3}$$

$$3\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{3}}+\dfrac{3}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{9-(49+4x^2-28x)}}{3}$$
$$3\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{3}}+\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}$$

In first and second method I am getting the different results of $\dfrac{3}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{2x-7}{3}$ and $3\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{3}}$ respectively. I checked that these are not inter-convertible. Why am I getting this difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques). For this case I would suggest the third approach from there (differentiate).

Comment: i am talking in respect to this question especially, so that doesn't answer my question

Comment: Have you read that posts? Both your approaches are correct and they only differ by a constant, which I would suggest to use when you deal with an indefinite integral.

Comment: actually there should not be difference of a constant also, because whatever standard integrations I have used, those are exact.

Comment: both approaches are correct, the difference is in a constant which appears to be ${3\pi}\over 4$

Comment: can you prove it?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m5lqnib5mk

Comment: @Zacky, can you please reopen the question, what's your hurry?

Comment: I can't reopen the question alone, it takes $5$ votes, or a vote from a user with a gold badge and I believe it's rightfully marked as a duplicate as I mentioned, there's no issue with your approaches, they just differ by a constant.
From the method $1$ the integral is: $$\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}+\dfrac{3}{2}\sin^{-1}\dfrac{2x-7}{3}+C_1$$
And from the second one: $$3\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{3}}+\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}+C_2$$
You computed a collection of antiderivatives there. They all can differ by a contant. Please read the answer from there.

Comment: Note that you can also write your resullt as: $$3\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\dfrac{x-2}{3}}+\sqrt{\left(5-x\right)\left(x-2\right)}+12345 \ln 2 +\pi^5 -e^{C_2}$$
It still differs by a constant.
And you can even write it as:
$$\sqrt{(5-x)(x-2)}-3\arctan\sqrt{ \left(\frac{5-x}{x-2}\right)}+C_3$$ 
As a third method (just let $\frac{5-x}{x-2}=t$ from the beginning to obtain this form). But all three antiderivatives are correct and they only differ by a constant.

Comment: You can show they differ by a constant but it is a hell of a lot difficult. Consider $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1} \left( \frac{2x-7}{3} \right)$ and $\beta =\sin^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{x-2}{3}} \right) $. Then you have to show $\sin(3\alpha-3\beta) = \sin(3(\alpha-\beta))$ is a constant. It is computationally hard but possible.

Comment: @user3290550 : You wrote: "actually there should not be difference of a constant also, because whatever standard integrations I have used, those are exact". That is incorrect. Exact methods should yield things differing by a constant. "Constant" in this context means not depending on $x.$ If something does not depend on $x,$ then its derivative with respect to $x$ is $0.$

Answer (score 2):

Both your answers are correct. Your two functions differ by $3\pi/4$, so they have the same derivative.

Let $b=\sqrt{\frac{x-2}3}$. For your integral to make sense you need $0\leq b\leq1$ (this comes from $2\leq x\leq5$). Let $a=\arcsin b$. Note $0\leq\arcsin b\leq \tfrac\pi2$, and so the sine is injective when applied to $2a-\tfrac\pi2$. Then
\begin{align}
\sin\left(2a-\tfrac\pi2\right)
&=-\cos(2a)=-(1-2\sin^2a)=2b^2-1.
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
2\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{x-2}3}\ -\frac\pi2
&=2\arcsin b -\frac\pi2=2a-\frac\pi2\\ \ \\
&=\arcsin(2b^2-1)\\ \ \\
&=\arcsin\frac{2x-7}3.
\end{align}
Then, multiplying by $3/2$, 
$$
3\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{x-2}3}\ -\frac{3\pi}4=\frac32\,\arcsin\frac{2x-7}3.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Shown below is that the two results differ by a constant 
$-\frac{3\pi}4$.

Define $f(x)$ as the difference of the two results

$$f(x)=\frac32\sin^{-1}\frac{2x-7}3-3\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{x-2}3}$$

where $2<x\le5$. Then, evaluate

$$f’(x) = \frac3{2\sqrt{(5-x)(x-2)}}- \frac3{2\sqrt{(5-x)(x-2)}}=0$$

Thus, $f(x)$ is a constant over $(2,5]$ and can be evaluated with

$$f(x)=f(5)=\frac32\cdot \sin^{-1} 1 -3\sin^{-1}1=-\frac{3\pi}4$$

Comment: You are right, my bad.