# Two possible answers of $\int\frac{x}{4x-1}dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following ODE
$$y'=\frac{xe^{y}}{4x-1}$$
with $y(0)=0$. From the equation, I get
$$\int e^{-y}dy=\int\frac{x}{4x-1}dx$$
In the second integral, if $u=4x-1\Rightarrow x=(u+1)/4$ and $du=4dx$; hence
$$\int\frac{x}{4x-1}dx=\frac{1}{16}(4x-1+\ln|4x-1|)$$
but, if I evaluate the second integral using long division:
$$\frac{x}{4x-1}=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{4x-1}\right)$$
my final answer will be
$$\int\frac{x}{4x-1}dx=\frac{1}{4}\left(x+\frac{1}{4}\ln|4x-1|\right)=\frac{1}{16}(4x+\ln|4x-1|)$$

so, I have two possible solutions:
$$-e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x-1+\ln|4x-1|)+c$$
or
$$-e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x+\ln|4x-1|)+c$$
with $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Using the fact $y(0)=0$, in the first equation
$$c=-\frac{15}{16}$$
and in the second one
$$c=-1$$
Which one is correct and why?

Comment: They’re the same?

Comment: @mjqxxxx what do you mean?

Comment: Both are correct.

Comment: @mvfs314 $c$ is an arbitrary constant, that happens to be different in your two solutions. Thus making the overall solution the same.

Comment: See that $-1$ in the bracket in the first solution - that gives the $\frac 1{16}$ difference

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the solution of the given differential equation as $$-e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x-1+\ln|4x-1|)+c\tag1$$where $c$ is an arbitrary constant  and it can be written as $$-e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x-1+\ln|4x-1|)+c\\\implies -e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x+\ln|4x-1|)+c'\tag2$$where $~c'=c-1/16~$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now putting the initial condition $~y(0)=0~,$ from $(1)$ you get $~c=-15/16~$ and from $(2)$ you get $~c'=-1~.$

Now putting $~c=-15/16~$ in equation $(1)$, you get
$$-e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x-1+\ln|4x-1|)-\frac{15}{16}\\\implies -e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x+\ln|4x-1|)-1\tag3$$
Again putting $~c'=-1~$ in equation $(2)$, you get
$$-e^{-y}=\frac{1}{16}(4x+\ln|4x-1|)-1$$which is same as equation $(3)$.

So from here you can find that the particular solution of the given differential equation is same in both cases and it is independent of the choice of the arbitrary constant.

**Therefore your both answers are correct and you are free to choose any one of them.**