# Brainfreeze, can't integrate $x-1$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

If $f(x)=x-1$, I want to find
$$ \int (x-1) \ dx $$. I make a variable substitution z = x-1, dx = dz so it becomes
$$ \int z \ dz \\ = \frac{z^2}{2} + C $$. If I now substitute back $z=x-1,$ I get:
$$ \int x-1 \ dx = \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} + C $$

Now if I do it another way without variable substitution I get:
$$ \int x \ dx - \int 1 \ dx = \frac{x^2}{2} - x  + C$$

What is going on here since these answers seem different to me? Are they both right but the constans $C$ are different or what am I missing here?

Comment: Two antiderivatives differs in a constant. Just expand the 1st solution

Comment: This is why I hate indefinite integrals and the “$+C$”.

Comment: One way to avoid such ambiguity is to work with definite integrals instead, e.g., $$F_0(x)=\int_0^x (x'-1)\,dx'=\frac12 x^2-x,\quad F_1(x) =\int_1^x (x'-1)\,dx'=\frac12 (x-1)^2.$$ Note that $F_1(x)-F_0(x)=\int_0^1 (x-1)\,dx = -1/2$, so the two indeed differ by a constant. Whether this is an improvement will, in part, depend on your stomach for dummy variables.

Comment: @Deane I absolutely agree. Every time I see a $\int$ without a domain of integration I cringe - what does it mean geometrically? If one wants an arbitrary integral they should write $\int_a^x (t-1)\,\textrm{d}t$ for an arbitrary constant $a$.

Comment: Check the derivatives of both the answers, i.e, another way to check if they differ by a constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers are correct.

$$\begin{align}\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}&=\frac{x^2-2x+1}{2}\\
&=\frac{x^2}2-x+\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

So your two solutions differ by a constant.

Comment: Which equivalent answer is considered the most simplified or generally preferred form?

Comment: There isn’t really a preferred answer, as far as I know. I think $x^2/2-x+C$ solution is simpler to derive, and generalizes to all polynomials, but there is an elegance to the substitution method, too, and might even be preferred when integrating something like $(x-1)^3.$

Answer (score 5):

Both answers are correct. Indefinite integrals are defined up to a constant C.

Answer (score 1):

First solution: $${\dfrac {(x-1)^2}{2} + C = \dfrac {(x^2-2x+1)}{2}+C = \dfrac {x^2}{2}-x + \dfrac {1}{2}+C}.$$  The $\dfrac {1}{2} +C$ is also constant; thus, both solutions are correct.

Comment: Which equivalent answer (entailing both solutions differing by a constant of integration) is considered the most simplified or generally preferred form? The most expanded vs factorized one?

Comment: Why write $\rightarrow$ when $=$ will do?

Comment: It depends on how much you want it simplified.  If you prefer your solution neater, use the first method of substitution and do not expand your solution; otherwise, you can integrate term separately.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You know, I had that first and then thought arrows would be better, but you're right - equals signs work much better.  I've corrected my post.