# Same integration question yields to 2 possible answers; why?

Tags: calculus, integration

In looking at the equality

$$\int \frac{a}{b(c-x)}dx = \int dt$$

I obtained different answers via different methods.

Via one method, I got

$$- \frac{a}{b} \ln(c-x) = t+C$$

Via another, I got

$$- \frac a b \ln(b(c-x)) = t+C$$

How is this possible?

Comment: A couple things...  The best place for question content is in the question body, not at an external location which requires a click; this is usually best accomplished with MathJAX.  Also, there is no question here...  What type of answer are you expecting?

Comment: Both the answers differ by a 'constant' term only. Nothing is wrong in that.

Comment: There must be a duplicate with zillions of linked questions...

Comment: @metamorphy there's an faq written by Xander sometimes ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques)

Answer (score 4):

The $C$ in both answers are not the same, assuming $a,b,c$ are constants.

Note that

$$-\frac a b \ln(b(c-x)) = - \frac{a}{b} \ln(b) - \frac a b \ln(c-x) = t + K$$

If we set $K = C - a \ln(b) / b$, then it becomes equivalent to your first result.