# Why am i getting two different answers for two different ways of solving the integral.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

So the Integral is $$\int \frac {dt}{t(t+1)^2}$$ So i thought of it two ways.

1.Substituting $\displaystyle y=\frac 1t$

Solution:  $\displaystyle \ln\left|\frac{t}{1+t}\right|-\frac{t}{1+t}$

2.Substituting $\displaystyle y=\frac {1}{1+t}$

Solution: $\displaystyle \ln\left|\frac{t}{1+t}\right|+\frac {1}{1+t}$

Here's the photo for reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxJGi.jpg)

Comment: Both look OK, they differ by a constant. +C...

Comment: Your answers differ by the constant $1$. So, both are valid. Add $1$ to your first answer and see. You'll get the second answer.

Comment: When in doubt that the integral is wrong, compute the derivative

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.Substituting $\displaystyle y=\frac 1t$
>
> Solution:  $\displaystyle \ln\left|\frac{t}{1+t}\right|-\frac{t}{1+t}$
>
> 2.Substituting $\displaystyle y=\frac {1}{1+t}$
>
> Solution: $\displaystyle \ln\left|\frac{t}{1+t}\right|+\frac {1}{1+t}$

Note that:

$$\frac{1}{1+t}=-\frac{t}{1+t}+1$$

your two solutions differ by a constant $1$, hence both of them are correct.