# Why do I get 2 different integral solutions?

Tags: calculus, integration

So the first is obvious:
$$\int \frac{1}{2x+2} dx = \frac{1}{2}\ln(2x+2) + C$$
Now, what if I do something like this:
$$\int \frac{1}{2x+2} dx = \int \frac{1}{2(x+1)} dx = (\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{x+1} dx) =\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1) + C$$
Why can't I "take" the half out of the integral?
(Sorry if the formatting is weird)

Comment: This is a megaduplicate. See for instance [Getting different answers when integrating using different techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques)

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio so it's all a matter of what constant I choose?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Your two approaches resulted in answers that only differed by a constant.

Comment: Please recall, that $\ln(k\cdot X)=\ln k + \ln X.$ In your case, a multiplier $2$ from within logarithm jumps outside as a $\ln 2$ addend and then gets assimilated by the $C$ constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int [1/(2x+2)]dx=(1/2)(\ln|2x+2|)+C.$$ Further approaching we will get, $$(1/2)(\ln|x+1|)+(\ln|2|)/2+C.$$ Now we can write $$(\ln|2|)/2+C =C_1.$$ So, the final result will be $$(1/2)(\ln|x+1|)+C_1.$$