# What is $\int {\sqrt {1 + 2\sin(x)\cos(x)}dx}$?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble solving this problem. So I got that $\sqrt {1 + 2\sin(x)\cos(x)} = \sqrt{(\sin(x) + \cos(x))^2}$ using the Pythagorean Identity for 1, but then I get $\lvert \sin(x) + \cos(x) \rvert$ under the integral sign, and I don't know what to do from here. If I go to the integral calculator (https://www.integral-calculator.com/), it just gives $\sin(x) - \cos(x)$ + C.

Could someone please help?

Comment: If you insist on going with $|\sin x + \cos x|$, you can just type that into the calculator. I know from experience that the calculator you mentioned would give you a result.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of absolute value to see how you might express this without using absolute value and go from there?

Comment: There was a question about it, but it is hard to find, where you got [similar result](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/03/01/01/0003/) for $\int\sqrt{1+\sin(t)}dt$

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I mean, I guess I could use a piecewise function or something. But then why does the integral calculator give sin(x) - cos(x) + C?

Comment: @Accelerator thanks, this does give a different value and I can see the steps, but shouldn't the original integral give the same result? I get $-\dfrac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{\left|\sin\left(x\right)+\cos\left(x\right)\right|}$

Comment: Using $cos(2x)=cos^2x-sin^2x$ then factoring and dividing gives $\pm(cos( x) - sin( x))$ which is your original solution, but I'm using the $\pm$ because the parity matters due to the absolute value.  So I come back to using the piecewise view of this. Try graphing $sin(x)+cos(x)$ then $|sin(x)+cos(x)|$ e.g. in Desmos.

Comment: It's possible to solve an indefinite integral in various ways and get answers that look different, but the constant of integration would make the "different answers" agree. [More details here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques). You could also differentiate your answer and see if you get the original integrand back.

Comment: @JonahGeorge, I guess you possibly can apply Taylor series for $sin(x)+cos(x)$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int{|\sin(x)+ \cos (x)|} \,\mathrm dx=
\begin{cases}
-\cos(x) +\sin(x) +C_1, & \text{if }\sin(x)+ \cos (x) > 0 \\
\cos(x) -\sin(x) + C_2, & \text{if }\sin(x)+ \cos (x)<0
\end{cases}$$
we need a function
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $\sin(x)+ \cos (x) > 0$ } \\
-1, & \text{if $\sin(x)+ \cos (x)<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
So
$$f(x):=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x=k\pi -\frac{\pi}{4}$ for any integer $k$  } \\
\frac{\sin(x)+ \cos (x)}{|\sin(x)+ \cos (x)|}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This gives
$$\int{|\sin(x)+ \cos (x)|} \,\mathrm dx = (-\cos(x) +\sin(x))f(x) +C
$$

btw there is a function that behave like $f(x)$ which is $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$.

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x):=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x=0$  } \\
\frac{x}{|x|}, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

then $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(x)+ \cos (x))$ so the antiderivative is
$$
(-\cos(x) +\sin(x))\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(x)+ \cos (x))+C.
$$

Comment: This function is not continuous. At the first step, the constants can be different for each interval. One has to choose them to make the integral continuous.

Comment: @LL3.14 you are right I didn't notice that at all ,I guess my answer is wrong then, should I delete it ?

Comment: You got the first part, just correct it ;-)

Comment: The integral graphs do [not fully match](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/goymq0k) even though they are both off by a constant on an interval.

Answer (score -3):

$$1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)=(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2$$
HENCE $$∫\sqrt{1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)}dx=∫\sqrt{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2}dx=∫(\sin(x)+\cos(x))dx
=\sin(x)-\cos(x)+C$$
is the final answer

Comment: Have you considered the fact that for some values $v\in\mathbb R$ it might happen that $\sqrt{ v^2 } \ne v$...?